# Taking a list of strings and replacing multiple words with one

Tags: string, list, haskell, recursion

I'm fairly new to Haskell and as input I want to take an array of string for example as
`["HEY" "I'LL" "BE" "RIGHT" "BACK"]` and look for lets say `"BE" "RIGHT" "BACK"` and replace it with a different word, lets say `"CHEESE"`. I have a function made for single words but I want this to work if a string contains a certain phrase to replace it with a word. Oh and I don't want to use external libraries.

Code:

```
replace :: [String] -> [String]
replace [] = []
replace (h:t)
    | h == "WORD" = "REPLACED" : replace t
    | otherwise = h : replace t
```

Comment: So what is your code for a replacing a single word?  That would help with performing it for multiple words.

Comment: Okay I will edit the original post

Comment: So how would you modify your `replace` function so that it has the type signature `replace :: String -> String -> [String] -> [String]` so that you can pass in the value you want to search for and the value you want to replace?  Something like `replace old new (h:t) = ...`

Comment: It doesn't nesserarly have to follow the way I'm doing it line by line. I just need an idea or hint so to say. Cause I can do the 4 declarations but I wouldn't know what to do then

Comment: Have you tried out the `elem` function?  It tests if an element is in a list.

Comment: Yeah I have however how will I 

a) remove the 3 elements from the list to replace with the word
b) have it will only replace the word if the words its looking for are side by side and not scattered within the list

Comment: Ah, I understand what your actual problem is, you want to replace a sub-list with a new value, not each individual word with a new value.  I'll provide some additional help in an answer.

Comment: Alright cool. Thank you so much for your help so far :)

Comment: Is there anyway to compare ("BE":"RIGHT":"BACK":rest) in a guard?

Answer (score 1):

What you have now could also be implemented as

```
replace ("WORD":rest) = "REPLACED" : replace rest
replace (x:rest) = x : replace rest
replace [] = []
```

And this could be extended to your example as

```
replace ("BE":"RIGHT":"BACK":rest) = "CHEESE" : replace rest
replace (x:rest) = x : replace rest
replace [] = []
```

But obviously this is not a great way to write it.  We'd like a more general solution where we can pass in a phrase (or sub-list) to replace.  To start with we know the following things:

1. Input is a list of `n` elements (decreases as we recurse)
2. Phrase is a list of `m` elements (stays constant as we recurse)
3. If `m > n`, we definitely don't have a match
4. If `m <= n`, we might have a match
5. If we don't have a match, keep the head and try with the tail

While there are more efficient algorithms out there, a simple one would be to check our lengths at each step along the list.  This can be done pretty simply as

```
--             Phrase    Replacement  Sentence   New sentence
replaceMany :: [String] -> String -> [String] -> [String]
replaceMany phrase new sentence = go sentence
    where
        phraseLen = length phrase
        go []   = []
        go sent@(x:xs)
            | sentLen < phraseLen = sent
            | first == phrase     = new : go rest
            | otherwise           = x : go xs
            where
                sentLen = length sent
                first   = take phraseLen sent
                rest    = drop phraseLen sent
```

Here we can take advantage of Haskell's laziness and just go ahead and define `first` and `rest` without worrying if it's valid to do so.  If they aren't used, they never get computed.  I've opted to also use some more complex pattern matching in the form `sent@(x:xs)`.  This matches a list with at least one element, assigning the entire list to `sent`, the first element to `x`, and the tail of the list to `xs`.  Next, we just check each condition.  If `sentLen < phraseLen`, there's no possible chance that there's a match in the rest of the list so just return the whole thing.  If the first `m` elements equals our phrase, then replace it and keep searching, and otherwise just put back the first element and keep searching.